# Achieving impersonation within Spfx webparts

Tags: office-365, spfx-webparts, impersonation

A user fills a form in a spfx webpart. Correspondingly I have to create an item in a list for this Metadata. What I would like to do is achieve this, but restrict the user from directly accessing/modifying items within the same list. But in client side web parts, code is able to do what user is able to do. Any suggestions how I could achieve impersonation and modify the list without providing user with the access to the list?

Answer (score 1):

"Both SharePoint Framework Extensions and user custom action or ECB menu item solutions run in the browser and can contain only client-side JavaScript code. Client-side solutions have a number of limitations, **such as not being able to elevate permissions in SharePoint** or reach out to external APIs that don't support cross-origin communication (CORS) or authentication using OAuth implicit flow. In such cases, the client-side solution could leverage a remote server-side API to perform the necessary operation and return the results to the client."

Check [Use only client-side code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-user-customactions-to-spfx-extensions) part.

Comment: Lee can't we call a workflow or an Addin from the client side code to achieve this?

Comment: You may use add-in part(can be insert to modern page), so you could elevate permission in add-in.

Comment: So will the client side code in Spfx will communicate with the app part present on the modern page?

Comment: I mean use add-in part instead of SPFx, PatMill_MSFT mentioned another approach by creating Azure App, while it's more complex solution. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/194793/can-a-user-update-a-sharepoint-list-using-spfx-without-the-user-having-access-to/194804